# Script to automate some website navigation

Tags: web, scripting, navigation

does anyone know whether there is a way of programming a script that will allow me to automate some website navigation (like clicking checkboxes, selecting from drop down lists, etc.)? The specific problem I'm trying to solve is this: I need to log into my webmail and automatically select my emails from the inbox and move them to another folder. Rackspace only allows you to see/select 100 emails at a time and I have about 130,000 so that is repeating the same action 13,000 times!... Thanks for your help!

Comment: 30-day free trial of automation anywhere :-)

Answer (score 0):

GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey is a very popular alternative, uses JavaScript.

Firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Chrome (TamperMonkey):
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en

Website:
http://www.greasespot.net/